# How does in-place operation of list work

Tags: python-3.x

This is my code:

```
x=[1,3,2]
def foo(x):
    x.sort()
    x = x + [4,5]
    x.extend([6,7])
    return x

foo(x)
print(x)
```

i expect the printed list to be [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] but i got [1,2,3] instead. I read that this is due to in-place operation because it returns None, but ive included return x into my code but it still does not work.

Comment: After `x = x + [4,5]`, you're not working with the original list any more. https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html is relevant.

Comment: Also, you're not doing anything with `foo`'s return value.

Comment: @user2357112 now i added an additional line, print(x) before return x, this prints [1,2,3,4,5,6,7].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues here: the scope of `x`, and the return value.

When you declare `x = x + [4, 5]`, `x` isn't the same list anymore

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> id(x)
4501926472
>>> x = x + [4, 5]
>>> id(x)
4501926616
>>>
```

Thus, `x` inside `foo` refers to a *local* `x`, not the *global* `x` defined outside of the function.

Furthermore, you do not store the return `x` from `foo`, so it disappears, for all practical purposes.

Comment: what do you mean by i did not return x from foo?

Answer (score 0):

## You have to tell python to print the returned value of  x after the foo method is executed , you told python to print x , witch you defined as x=[1,3,2]  , you have to print the value of x after it goes through the foo method

```
x=[1,3,2]
def foo(x):
    x.sort()
    x = x + [4,5]
    x.extend([6,7])
    return x


print(foo(x))
```